# Why explicit conversion from object to long (Unboxing) is not allowed in C#?

Tags: c#, unboxing, explicit-conversion

I was reading unboxing and came across this code:

`object obj = 22;`

`long l = (long)obj;`

when I ran this code, it throws an exception `InvalidCastException`

I do not understand why?

For example Microsoft documentation on [Boxing and Unboxing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/boxing-and-unboxing) shows similar example that works:

```
int i = 123;
// The following line boxes i.
object o = i;
o = 123;
i = (int)o;  // unboxing
```

Comment: What makes you think the compiler would interpret the literal `22` as a `long` (and not an `int`)?

Comment: That's because `22` is an int. Try `object obj = 22L;` instead.

Comment: I've added results of your research to the question (please do that yourself for future question). I'm afraid it made question a bit more confusing - so please [edit] to add your version of the research and your reasoning why your code should work.

Comment: Or do: `long l = Convert.ToInt64(obj);`